# Auto-fill Google doc from Google Sheets form submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a Google form to auto-fill a Google doc. The script I have works up to the point of creating the new file from the template and places it in the correct location folder.
However none of the text which should be being replaced is being replaced, I have double and triple checked that everything matches from the template doc to the script and I am at a loss to what I am missing which is preventing it from working.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this code?

```
function Autofillgoogledocfromform(e) {
  var oneDate = e.values[1];
  var oneName = e.values[2];
  var oneALCI = e.values[3];
  var oneIndoorOutdoor = e.values[4];
  var oneObservationNote = e.values[5];
  var oneWhatdowethinkthistellsus = e.values[6];
  var oneEYFSBPMLinks = e.values[7];
  var twoDate = e.values[8];
  var twoName = e.values[9];
  var twoALCI = e.values[10];
  var twoIndoorOutdoor = e.values[11];
  var twoObservationNote = e.values[12];
  var twoWhatdowethinkthistellsus = e.values[13];
  var twoEYFSBPMLinks = e.values[14];

  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1F2gDifE915_yF6lizwZL55reBnecg4EQ'); 

  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1qwg-4_HMl2tNiLKqXTyjoXSuWeKtj4ZO')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(oneDate, folder); 

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getID());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText('{{Date}}', oneDate);
  body.replaceText('{{oneName}}', oneName);
  body.replaceText('{{oneALCI}}', oneALCI);
  body.replaceText('{{oneIndoorOutdoor}}', oneIndoorOutdoor);
  body.replaceText('{{oneObservationNote}}', oneObservationNote);
  body.replaceText('{{oneWhatdowethinkittellsus}}', oneWhatdowethinkthistellsus);
  body.replaceText('{{oneEYFSBPMLinks}}', oneEYFSBPMLinks);
  body.replaceText('{{twoDate}}', twoDate);
  body.replaceText('{{twoName}}', twoName);
  body.replaceText('{{twoALCI}}', twoALCI);
  body.replaceText('{{twoIndoorOutdoor}}', twoIndoorOutdoor);
  body.replaceText('{{twoObservationNote}}', twoObservationNote);
  body.replaceText('{{twoWhatdowethinkittellsus}}', twoWhatdowethinkthistellsus);
  body.replaceText('{{twoEYFSBPMLinks}}', twoEYFSBPMLinks);

  doc.saveAndClose();

}
```

Comment: Try capturing the event object with Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e)) and then take that object and use it in an intermediate function that calls your function and that way you can use the debugger to figure out what's happening.  It looks like your only using e.values so this will probably work.  The code seems pretty close to me.

Answer (score 0):

copy.getID() is not a function.  It should be copy.getId()

I fixed the getId() issue and used a modified version of your code which worked.

```
function Autofillgoogledocfromform(o) {
  const [,a,b,c,d,e,f] = o.values;
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1Y5wzuZwXML7S60p1iVP--rB7ELTpkeSPHXQnqFtiplc'); 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('11qVant2dOEdLYnbxZVJvmiyoIkfhWjQR')
  var copy = file.makeCopy(a, folder); 
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
  var body = doc.getBody();
  body.replaceText('{{Item1}}',a);
  body.replaceText('{{Item2}}',b);
  body.replaceText('{{Item3}}',c);
  body.replaceText('{{Item4}}',d);
  body.replaceText('{{Item5}}',e);
  body.replaceText('{{Item6}}',f);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

If you were not getting errors then perhaps you were not looking at the executions which is the sixth item down from the top of the sidebar menu.

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)